# Can "fluvial" be applied to man-made flooding?

Tags: word-usage

I was taught in my first year geology class that fluvial meant meant "relating to water", but [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fluvial) defines it as such:

> Geology:
>
> Of or found in a river.

Could I use "fluvial" to describe water originating from a man-made source, e.g.:

"There was a significant fluvial deposit left on the road from the flooding caused by the burst pipe."

If it is not valid, what would be?

Comment: Use "diluvial". ....

Comment: ...or "diluvian."

Comment: Sorry, but why are you wanting to use such a high register word to describe a puddle?

Comment: @KarlG, So I know which word to use when it causes a really big puddle. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the dictionary at geology.com [does not appear to carry *fluvial*](https://geology.com/dictionary/glossary-f.shtml), the [dictionary of geography at itseducation.asia](http://www.itseducation.asia/geography/f.htm) gives the following definition:

> *lit.* **of a river. Used to distinguish processes and landforms from similar ones that may be produced by a different agent,** e.g. fluvial deposition rather than glacial deposition.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fluvial) defines *fluvial* as follows:

> 1 **of, relating to, or living in a stream or river**
>
> 2 **produced by the action of a stream**
>
> *a fluvial plain*

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fluvial) gives the following definition:

> *adjective, geology*
>
> **Of or found in a river.**
>
> *‘fluvial processes’*
>
> *‘fluvial deposits’*
>
> *Origin*
>   Middle English: from Latin *fluvialis*, from *fluvius* ‘river’, from *fluere* ‘to flow’.

In particular, note the etymology given.

The [Online Dictionary of Etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fluvial#etymonline_v_8953) agrees:

> "**pertaining to a river**,"
>
> late 14c., from Latin *fluvialis* "of a river," from *fluvius* "a river, stream, running water," related to *fluere* "to flow" (see *fluent*).

**As far as I can see, you can look through [all the definitions Onelook finds](https://www.onelook.com/?w=fluvial&ls=a) for *fluvial* and none of them give any suggestion that *fluvial* can be used in any context other than in reference to rivers.** *Ponds* and *streams* is as far a stretch from a river as any goes, in the [1913 Webster](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/fluvial). (A rather pedantic argument could be made that as *fluvial* derives from a word referring to flowing water it is applicable even to a broken drain, but I can't find any evidence for current usage to lend credence to this kind of speculation.)

Moreover, the sense the geographical dictionary entry above gives would suggest that flooding from a pipe would be specifically excluded from the meaning of *fluvial*, and that it would be misleading to use the word in such a context.

---

Based on all this, I would say that the answer to your question

> *Could I use "fluvial" to describe water originating from a man-made source[?]*

is no, not in the case at hand, despite what you were taught.

(However, I would see no problem using it in relation to deposits from, say, a diverted river, which is arguably a man-made source, albeit one that is still a river.)

To go on, your example sentence works perfectly well without *fluvial* and is completely clear without anything taking its place:

> *There was a significant deposit left on the road from the flooding caused by the burst pipe.*

Comment: @KJO I tend towards removing words rather than adding them, though I don't presume to be definitive in my suggestion. In your example, if it's a piped-up river (or a part thereof) I think you could use _fluvial_ without any trouble, particularly when referring to the particles carried and their origin. I'd think a fully enclosed river like the Fleet in London could still be said to leave _fluvial deposits_. ($0.02, FWIW.)